# android: How to force TableRows to have the same height?

Tags: android, layout, height, tablelayout, tablerow

I have searched google and stackoverflow thoroughly, but the only answer I get is: set each `Tablerow` with `layout weight = "1"`. This doesnt work.

Now I have eight rows in a `TableLayout`, and each contains 5 `LinearLayouts`. Each of the LinearLayouts contains 2 `TextViews`, and the `FontSizes` vary from `TextView` to `TextView`.

It turns out that the TableRows vary in height, depending on the Fontsizes of the contained `TextViews`.
Strangely enough, it doesnt have any impact on the layout whether I set the layout_height of the TableRows to "0dp" or to "match_parent" or "fill_parent".

How can I force the `TableRows` to have the same height? I dont want to use a specific pts value as height, because the tableRows must divide the whole screen equally between themselves.

Here is part of the xml, the actual file is huge:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:weightSum="8"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/btnmargintop"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/btnmarginbot"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/btnmarginleft"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnmarginright"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg" >

            <myapp.TypefacedTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="@integer/layoutweight1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                stevens:typeface="myfont.otf"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize1" />
            <myapp.TypefacedTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="@integer/layoutweight2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                stevens:typeface="myfont.otf"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize2" />              
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your code and your XML.

Comment: could you make something of it, Phil?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Android developer Documentation of TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout), you cannot do that.

> The children of a TableLayout cannot specify the `layout_width`
> attribute. Width is always `MATCH_PARENT`. However, the `layout_height`
> attribute can be defined by a child; default value is
> `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`. If the child is a TableRow, then
> the height is always `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`.

However, you can use a vertical LinearLayout to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably letting the layout of your tab to automatically adjust to the size of the content inside. There are two ways, to settle things down:

- Make sure all the elements share the same size - that being said, don't worry about the table as a whole, just make sure, that the dimensions of the elements inside are the same
- Or simply set the height of the parent layout and don't let the elements make a difference. Problem with this solution is, that if you get bigger inside, you'll be out of space, so you may want to stick with the first option

Comment: i am not exactly sure, but i think by option 1 you mean that i set the height of each row to a fixed pts value? i dont want that though, because then, depending on screen size, the table wont fill the screen..

Comment: Yes, exactly! Make all the elemnts the same size(= find the maximum size it can have) and in that way, you'll have the same height for all rows. Why would you need to fit it on screen, it will adjust + the user can scroll down ;)

Comment: Well thank you for your help, but I need it to fit the screen. scrolling is not an option.

Comment: In that case, option two is the way, you need to go.

Comment: Set `weight` for each row to be the same and make height `fill_parent`. In that way, you'll have all the rows the same size and fit the screen without scrolling.

Comment: i am sorry, but that is the way i tried it, it does not work for some reason. i mentioned that in my question too.

Comment: You mentioned you tried setting weight to 1. Have you also set the **height** to fill_parent? I don't see that in the code.

Comment: I tried this, I edited it in my question. Strangely enough, it doesnt have any impact on the layout if I set the layout_height of the TableRows to "0dp" or to "match_parent" or "fill_parent".

Comment: Your code has a lot of `0dp` and other identifiers. I suggest stripping everything down, take a clean XML layout and put in table layout with eight rows, set the layout to fill parent and each row as well. Then set weight of each row to 1 and see what it does. Then add all the fields you need to have inside. It is a tedious work, but tweaking this huge XML may take you mroe time then to start from scratch.