# How to force TableRow have same height

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have the same problem, as these topics: [Fixed height of tableRow Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704376/fixed-height-of-tablerow-android?rq=1), [How to force TableRows to have the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137674/android-how-to-force-tablerows-to-have-the-same-height) But there I have not found an answer (((
  TableRow whis layout_width="match_parent", layout_height="0dp", android:layout_weight="1" and each TableRow contains few GridView. When GridView is empty, all TableRow has same height, but if add items, first row become higher.
My XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Set padding to table row.. you can adjust the height the same as other rows..